# On Windows, where does H2 database BACKUP TO?

Tags: backup, h2

Online mode H2 on Windows, backup by `BACKUP TO 'mybackup.zip'`

But, where is the `'mybackup.zip'`? Found almost everywhere, running directory, h2* lib directory, user directory, db directory, java/bin directory, nowhere found.

And `BACKUP TO 'C:/mybackup.zip'` or `BACKUP TO 'file:/C:/back.zip'` can run without error, but nothing happened in `C:\`.

```
BACKUP TO 'file:/C:/back.zip';
Update count: 0
(573 ms)
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `BACKUP TO` succeed in Shell mode, fails in browser H2 console.

`java -cp h2*.jar org.h2.tools.Shell`